# SwiftUI macOS detect closing of window

Tags: macos, swiftui

## Aim:

- I have a swiftUI app that uses Window scene
- When the user closes the red window, I would like call `f1()`

## My attempt:

`onDisappear` doesn't seem to be called when user closes the macOS app window

## Question:

1. In macOS (SwiftUI) how do I detect a window is closed by the user?
2. Am I missing something?

## Code

### App

```
@main
struct DemoApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
        
        Window("test", id: "test") {
            Color.red
                .onDisappear {
                    print("onDisappear")
                    f1()
                }
        }
    }
    
    func f1() {
        print("f1 called")
    }
}
```

### ContentView

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @Environment(\.openWindow) private var openWindow
    var body: some View {
        Button("show red") {
            openWindow(id: "test")
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For a "SwiftUI way" to do this, check out the environment property `controlActiveState`. This value will be set to `.inactive` when the window loses focus, and when the window is closed.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @Environment(\.controlActiveState) private var controlActiveState

    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello, World!")
            .onChange(of: controlActiveState) { newValue in
                switch newValue {
                case .key, .active:
                    break
                case .inactive:
                    // Do your stuff.
                @unknown default:
                    break
                }
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: Going "inactive" does not mean the window is closed ... so the question still is not answered, how to distinguish between CLOSED and INACTIVE ???

Comment: This does not distinguish between the window losing focus, and being closed.

Comment: As others have said, window going inactive will not work. You get a .onChange() to .inactive if your app gets swapped to the background, or (in macOS) if the user brings another window to the front.

Answer (score 4):

In case anyone will find this interesting I have approached the problem in a different (potentially better) way.

```
@main
struct DemoApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        Window("test", id: "test") {
            Color.red
                .task {
                    // perform action when window is opened
                    await Task.waitTillCancel()
                    // perform action after window is closed
                }
        }
    }
}

extension Task where Success == Void, Failure == Never {
    static func waitTillCancel() async {
        let asyncStream = AsyncStream<Int> { _ in }
        for await _ in asyncStream { }
    }
}
```

According to Apple documentation `.task` modifier creates a task that matches lifetime of the view and is cancelled when view is discarded. We can create infinite AsyncStream (empty but never finishing) to wait till taks is cancelled (hence window is closed in example above) and then perform required action.

I think this is the only properly documented case in SwiftUI when we can certainly detect when window is closed.

Comment: Great solution. This major feature should have been included in Apple's APIs.

Comment: I like this one very much

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `NSWindow.willCloseNotification` notification:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        
        Text("xyz")
            .onReceive(NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: NSWindow.willCloseNotification)) { newValue in
                print("close")
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a ton, just wondering if there was a SwiftUI way to do this? I was trying `scenePhase`, `isFocused` but couldn't find a way

Answer (score 1):

On Swift `5.10` Xcode `15.3` `onDismiss` seems to be working properly, I guess it was just a bug on the implementation.

[onDismiss](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/ondisappear(perform:)) is called when closing a `Window` (manually or programatically).

Example:

```swift
WindowGroup {
    ContentView()
        .onDisappear {
            // window was closed
        }
}
```